# Is the set $A$ open, closed, or what?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Question: The set $A$ is defined as $:=\{∈ℝ^2 : ||||≤2\}\setminus \{0\}$. Is the set A open? Is it closed?

My thoughts: To me this set looks closed since we have a $≤$ sign instead of a $<$ sign. However, there is $\setminus \{0\}$ term in the question which suggest that $\{0\}$ is not included in the set, which might suggest that the set is both open and closed? I'm not sure.

Comment: You must mention  which topology you take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check if it's either of them separatedly (assuming you're considering the usual topology in $\mathbb R^2$):

- **Open?** The answer is NO. Remember that, to be open, then $\forall x\in A$, $\exists$ $\varepsilon>0$ such that
  $$B(x;\varepsilon)\subseteq A,$$
  where $B(x;\varepsilon)$ denotes the ball of center $x$ and radius $\varepsilon$. It's clear that the point $(0,2)$ is inside $A$, but there's no $\varepsilon>0$ that verifies the ball is contained inside $A$ (since that ball will contain infinite points with modulus greater than $2$), so **A is not open**.
- **Closed?** The answer is also NO. Remember that a set $X$ is closed if and only if its complementary $X^c$ is open. Notice that
  $$A^c=\{(0,0)\}\cup\{x\in\mathbb R^2\mid||x ||>2\},$$
  and the property that all points of an open set must verify we showed earlier is clearly not verified for the point $(0,0)\in A^c$ (since the origin is an isolated point in $A^c$), so we conclude $A^c$ is not open, hence **$A$ is not closed**.

If you're familiar with the *interior* and *closure* concepts, it's pretty easy to see that $A^o\neq A$ (then it's not open) and that $\bar A\neq A$ (then it's not closed).

Answer (score 1):

Good thinking: I agree if the "$\setminus \{ 0 \}$" was missing then the set $A$ would be closed. Let's investigate the point $0$: can you find a sequence in $A$ converging to $0$? If you can, then $A$ cannot be closed.

On the other hand, if $A$ were open then every point of $A$ would be contained in an open ball in turn entirely contained in $A$. Does a generic point on the boundary (e.g. $(0, 2) \in A$) have such a ball?

Answer (score 0):

For $A$ to be open, for $\forall x\in A$, there should exist $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $B(x, r)\subset A$. We can see, though, that $\forall r$, $B(0, r)\subsetneq A$, since $0 \notin A$. Therefore, A is not open. On the other hand, for A to be open, $A^c$ should be open, but for all $r>0$ there exist points of $B(0, r)$ which are not in $A^c$, because 0 is an isolated point of $A^c$. Therefore, $A$ is not open nor closed.